# iOS 5/6 vs iOS 7 multiline label line spacing

Tags: ios, uilabel, ios7, core-text, textkit

I ran my app under iOS 7 and discovered that multiline labels (non-attributed, plain text) render with a small line spacing. Anyone knows what to do it with iOS 5 compatibility?

**iOS 5/6**

[image: iOS 5/6]

**iOS 7**

[image: iOS 7]

Comment: Did u get the solution?

Answer (score 18):

```
if(NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
{
    NSFont *font = /* set font */;

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    [paragraphStyle setLineSpacing: /* required line spacing */];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle };
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"strigil" attributes:attributes];

    [label setAttributedText: attributedString];
}
else
{
    /* old method */
}
```

Comment: if reducing linespacing to 0 'zero' is not sufficient, you should have a look to the "maximumLineHeight" property of the paragraphStyle.

Comment: @TwiterZX Reducing light height can create issue where some character colliding.

Comment: @Leo Natan I agree, this can produce an issue in text drawing if the maximumLineHeight is lower then the font lineheight.

Comment: @Leo Natan I used this to remove the font descender value as it is in uppercase, so for me in this case, it is safe. "maximumLineHeight = font.ascender".

Comment: @TwiterZX A letter like "Q" still has a descender, as well as other Unicode characters. But yeah, your comment should be considered as well.

Comment: Why `NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];` not showing any effect?

Comment: @SahebSingh Because I assume `alloc] init]` doesn't return the default paragraph style.

Answer (score 1):

I used MSLabel in iOS5/6.
After iOS7 released, MSLabel is still working normally.

Nothing different in labels between iOS5/6 and iOS7.
You can try MSLabel at https://github.com/LemonCake/MSLabel