# Decreasing line spacing on UITextView iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, ios7

I'm trying to create a UITextView with dynamically adjustable line spacing. For iOS 6, I'm using styleString to adjust the spacing, but since that solution does not work for iOS 7, I set layoutManager delegate and use

```
- (CGFloat)layoutManager:(NSLayoutManager *)layoutManager lineSpacingAfterGlyphAtIndex:(NSUInteger)glyphIndex withProposedLineFragmentRect:(CGRect)rect
    return textView.lineHeight;
}
```

which works great for increasing the line spacing but does not allow me to decrease the spacing lower than default spacing like:

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

Is there a way to decrease the line spacing for iOS 7 with layoutManager or any other solution?

Comment: I've been looking but nothing so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is another question that could help you. Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969339/1658749)

Have you tried it using AttributedString?

Comment: I did try AttributedString. 
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle];
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = textView.lineSpacing; added it to the AttributedString, and set textView attributedString to it, but it did nothing

Comment: Efesus, the code above doesn't work because "defaultParagraphStyle" returns NSParagraphStyle, not the mutable version. So you'd need to do [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy] instead.

Then you can set lineSpacing property to an absolute value, or you can just do paragraphStyle.lineSpacing += 5 or so to just increase default spacing by 5 points.